# Starting a docker container with a node.js app produces error; complains about PATH

Tags: node.js, docker

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for a while and need a little help.

I have a docker container built from a Dockerfile.  When I try to run that container (either interactively [-i] or detached [-d]), it produces the following error:

> 2014/06/04 21:17:40 exec: "node": executable file not found in $PATH

This is how I'm trying to start the container (made generic for security reasons):

> sudo docker run -i -t -p port:port containername:containerversion node /path/to/node/app/nodeapp.js

What is troublesome and confusing is that when I run the container without that command appended, I am able to cd into the directory /path/to/node/app and run:

> node nodeapp.js

This works fine for me.  Additionally, when I compare the contents of the "which node" command and the output of "echo $PATH", I see that everything is kosher.  So, why in the heck does this refuse to acknowledge that I am its master and it should do what I say?

Comment: How about using the absolute path to the node executable in the docker run?

Comment: Because it performs the tasks in the Dockerfile as root, I had to add ENV PATH to the Dockerfile with the same path as the user I was eventually going to run the container as.

Comment: FWIW, there is also an option (not fully consistent with your question) that you've accidentally overridden the node path externally (e.g. via mount / volume).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nodejs` should be work.

I don't know why, but it installed named `nodejs` not `node` in my case.

Comment: `node` is more common, though some Node installs will use `nodejs`, which is pretty awkward. Make sure you're installing in an expected way.

Answer (score 1):

In your Dockerfile, ensure your `WORKDIR` is set and the `CMD` instruction looks like one of the following:

`CMD ["npm", "start"]` or

`CMD ["node", "nodeapp.js"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like this:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -p port:port containername:containerversion /path/to/node/bin/node /path/to/node/app/nodeapp.js
```

It must be possible to add it to your path, but I don't know how. But even if you could, it still makes sense to use full path like above, because you wouldn't accidentally run a different `node` this way.